# QUdpsocket send and receive an image

Tags: image, qt, sockets, send

I want to grab the PC screen. I use QPixmap::grab, and I get a QPixmap. Then I want to send this image using QUdpsocket. The image has been already converted to binary.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/Udpserver.htm 's demo can send and receive the image, but use pixel, I wanna send all binary data each 250ms.

Comment: What is the question in all of this? What do you want to send? Binary data as a QByteArray? uchar*? What is not clear of the example you linked?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the whole image in one go, you could try using `QDataStream` for serialization of a `QByteArray`.

The problem with this is that a UDP packet has a limited size, and could get fragmented if too large, and while large packets may work on your LAN, they could get fragmented over the internet. As UDP doesn't provide ordering guarantees like TCP, the fragments could come in the wrong order without the QDataStream header. This is probably why in your linked example they are only sending a single line at a time.

You may want to read a comparison of TCP and UDP and evaluate which fits your needs better.